# Is this possible?? typedef int char?

Tags: c, embedded

I understand that typedef is used as alias. But if I use typedef in this form whether compiler throws error or type gets redefined to char or still it remains same with the int but just char as its synonym??

Comment: what happened when you tried it? :)

Comment: Er... let me compile that for you...

Answer (score 2):

You can't redefine a built-in type. The compiler would complain about the syntax of the statement. Here is an illustrative example for you, if you didn't try it yourself:

main.c:

```
typedef int char;
int main() {
    return 0; 
}
```

The gcc output, when you try to compile:

```
main.c:1: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers   
main.c:1: warning: useless type name in empty declaration
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't redefine a built-in type, and you can't use keywords as the name for a `typedef`.